# Import Account Settings in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, user-accounts

I had one user account with my name and then I enable my *Administrator* account.

Now I want to all my account settings from my user account to the Admin Account. Like desktop, my documents. browser, Visual studio configurations, etc,.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I think theMicrosoft Scanstate tool will handle that.[Technet Migrate Accounts](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd560787(WS.10).aspx)